# dhcp server or routing rules on a lan with internet server

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp, osx-mavericks, firewire

I have two machines : Imac with Mac OS 10.9.5 & a Debian 8 server headless
both have one ethernet interface and one firewire.

The DHCP is still on the router and has statics ip address, the two machines are configured with static config. I could now activate firewire on level 3 network with address `192.168.10.x` and can SSH both Mac and Debian.

The idea is to reach internet throught firewire from the Mac and throught the Debian server and close my Mac ethernet if I want. For now config is the exterior can reach directly on default apache/debian page but still I can't bridge or relay the internet connection between `eth0` and `fw0` on the Debian.

`brtcl` doesn't want to do it. I already configured DNS with `/etc/network/interfaces`. I can route directly with nat/pat on router the Debian to the ISP ip address and use my original gateway as a switch.

First I would like my Debian act as a router and keep the isp router as a switch, so the main question and choice to do now is about the Debian server:

1. What soft to use to relay interfaces?
2. Do I really need/configure DHCP server on Debian? Isn't routing enoough?
3. Do I need to change the layer for firewire interface?

Comment: Because Ethernet and FireWire are different, they cannot be bridged. The question is what you’re trying to achieve. Gigabit Ethernet offers superior performance.

Comment: one of skills is to get internet throught firewire and debian as router/firewall

Comment: if they cant be bridged route can do smthg? i could connect once with mac>syst pref> shring internet> firewire/firewire but it crashed all network